# Evernote Android-Job clears alarms when app is killed

Tags: android

I'm using the [Evernote Android-Job](https://github.com/evernote/android-job) to schedule notifications using the `setExact` method which uses Alarm Manager internally. Now the problem is when the app is killed all pending alarms are killed and are rescheduled when app opens.

Here's the official doc: https://github.com/evernote/android-job/blob/master/FAQ.md#why-arent-my-periodic-jobs-running-as-expected-on-android-5-or-higher

How can I user GCM Network Manager or Firebase Job Dispatcher to meet my requirements

Now is there any work around for this using the same library or should I consider using other ones?

Comment: I don't think you need a Evernote for simple Alarm.. Use only `AlarmManager`

Answer (score 0):

The library will reschedule the job (what means creating a new alarm for exact jobs) as soon as it gets a chance. E.g. after force closing the app, then alarm is created again after the user started the app again. After restarting the device the alarm is also created again.

Comment: I think this will give you a clear insight of what I was facing https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772984/alarm-manager-not-firing-when-app-is-killed-on-android-7-one-plus-3t

Comment: Turns out it happens only on One Plus 3 and 3T devices which run on 7.1.1, don't know about the earlier versions