# Alarm Manager not firing when app is killed on Android 7 (One Plus 3T)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

Since the introduction Doze Mode and App StandBy managing alarms have changed. The problem I'm facing is my alarm manager fires correctly on KitKat, Lolipop and Marshmellow devices but above API 23 it does not fire unless the app is in foreground or background. But if the app is killed, the alarms are stopped.

Checked out Google Keep Application on my Android 7, turns out it does the same.

But Google Calendar fires regardless of whether the app is killed or not.

Done some reading and found out `setExactAndAllowWhileIdle` method on the alarm manager ensures to break the doze mode and trigger your alarm.

But it does not work, is there anything I'm missing here?

Here's my code:

```
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationPublisher.class);

    alertIntent.putExtra("Hello", "Meal Time");

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) this.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    int id = (int) System.currentTimeMillis();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19) {
            alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, delay, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        } else {
            alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, delay, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
        }
    } else {
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, delay, PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, id, alertIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT));
    }
```

Broadcast Receiver:

```
public class NotificationPublisher extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String message = intent.getStringExtra("Hello");
    Log.d("Called", "Meal Time");
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <receiver android:name=".NotificationPublisher" />
```

Comment: Please explain, in precise technical terms, what "the app is killed" means. For example, if you are "killing" the "app" yourself, how are you doing this? `adb shell`? From the Android Monitor in Android Studio? By swiping a task off of the overview screen? By some device-supplied task manager? Something else? If it is any of the latter three, what is the device model that you are testing on? Alarms get wiped out on a "force stop", but not for normal process termination.

Comment: By swiping a task off the overview screen, I'm testing it on One plus 3T running Android 7.1.1

Comment: Presumably, OnePlus tied the swipe-off-the-overview-screen to a "force stop" operation. You can try to confirm this by running your app, swiping it off the overview screen, then visiting the app's page in Settings and seeing if "Force Stop" is enabled or not. If this is what OnePlus has done, there is absolutely nothing you can do about it.

Comment: Force stop was enabled when I swiped the app off the screen and checked settings

Comment: OK. Next test: run your app, at least to the point where you have scheduled your alarm. Run `adb shell dumpsys alarm` on the development machine and see if your alarm is scheduled (it should be, if it has been working outside this swipe scenario). Then, swipe the app off of the overview screen, then run `adb shell dumpsys alarm` again. If the alarm is now gone, they must have rigged up their own way to cancel outstanding alarms without a full "force stop", and there may be workarounds.

Comment: The logs are intact even after swiping the app off the screen -    +177ms 1 wakes 1 alarms, last -3m32s489ms:
      *walarm*:droid.veeresh.jobscheduling/.NotificationPublisher

Comment: OK, I'm stumped. I have no idea why your receiver would not be triggered by `AlarmManager`, since it appears that your alarm is still outstanding.

Comment: Ran the app on Google Pixel running 7.1.1 same as OnePlus 3T, worked fine with Pixel. Since a large number of our consumers may have OnePlus 3T, is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: Since I have no idea what the underlying problem is, I have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to this?

Comment: No, the problem persists! Also, I recently found that a "started service" does not survive when the app is swiped.

Comment: Because of battery optimisation it is not working,i turned off the battery optimisation of particular app , it is working fine in oneplus 3

Comment: You wanna white-list your app from battery optimisation, check this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/42651399/3752079

Comment: @all you need to remove app from battery optimization it works like charm

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because of battery optimisation it is not working,i turned off the battery optimisation of particular app, it is working fine in oneplus 3.

You wanna white-list your app from battery optimisation programatically, check this link [stackoverflow.com/a/42651399/3752079](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42651399/3752079)

Answer (score -1):

Try with adding below line for your alertIntent
myIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0,myIntent, 0);